# Selecting data only where a field is in consecutive sequence

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a data set that represents an individual and also years of being a customer. The data is loaded to my pandas dataframe for me to do quick analysis.

Name     Year
John       2012
John       2016
Bern        2011
Bern        2012

The challenge here is to identify names which only have 2 consecutive years.

I only want to select.

Name    Year
Bern       2011
Bern       2012

John obviously disqualifies as he had a break between his years with us.

Appreciate any help.

Sorry the tables are out of shape. On mobile at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) and [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html). Last you can [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) groups with length `2`:

```
print df

0  John  2012
1  John  2016
2  Bern  2011
3  Bern  2012
4   Jon  2011
5   Jon  2012
6   Jon  2013


print (df.Year.diff() == 1) | (df.Year.shift(-1).diff() == 1) 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
Name: Year, dtype: bool

df1 = df[(df.Year.diff() == 1) | (df.Year.shift(-1).diff() == 1) ]
print df1
   Name  Year
2  Bern  2011
3  Bern  2012
4   Jon  2011
5   Jon  2012
6   Jon  2013

print df1.groupby('Name').filter(lambda x: len(x) == 2)
   Name  Year
2  Bern  2011
3  Bern  2012
```